# Get unparsed HTML document from local file

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to figure out if there is any way to get the un-parsed version of an HTML document as a string from a local url, e.g starting with file:///C:/Users/...

Using XHR or fetch to get `document.location` will run well in Firefox v.64 but in Chrome i get the following message `Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/Users/Admin/Documents/webdev/test/index.html. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.`

Using `document.documentElement.outerHTML` or `document.documentElement.innerHTML` will not give me an exact copy of the user-written HTML since this will give me the DOMs parsed version.

Is there any way to work around this?

Note: Using a local server will solve this, but for the current use case this is not an option.

Comment: What do you mean with "Using ... will not give me an exact copy of the user-written HTML since this will give me the DOMs parsed version."? What is the difference between the "parsed" and "unparsed" verions of the HTML you're referring to?

Comment: From what i've noticed, the browser tries to correct minor errors in order to render a page. In the written HTML you may have a tag like `<td>Cell</texttd>` which the browser will correct to `<td>Cell</td>`. Elements may also switch order, being moved up or down in the DOM tree's hierarchy. Therefore i need the user-written document, without the helping hand of the browser.

Comment: Are you referring to the code you see though the Dev Tools? That does clean up some of the HTML, but it doesn't alter the actual code, it's just a representation for debugging purposes. If you right-click the page and "View page source", you'll see the raw HTML that is being loaded, which should be equal to the local file.

Comment: Yes exactly, but my problem is to extract the actual source code. When using both `innerHTML` and `outerHTML` i get the parsed version of the document. If i use fetch or XHR i get the raw source code, but this will not work if it is run as a local file.

Comment: Gotcha. In that case it depends on what exact use case / constraints you're solving for. You can fetch local files using programming languages that run on your OS, e.g. PHP's `file_get_contents()` without the need of a web server. JavaScript can't consistently solve for this across browsers. If you're the sole user of the application, maybe there's some browser flags you can alter to allow this (insecure) behavior.